# Determine number of repeated string in data

Tags: r, string, character, data-manipulation

I have data like this

```
1      AB
2      ZZ
3      BC
4      AB
5      ZZ
6      CC
```

and i want to determine number of time that every string is repeated, for example the result will be this data

```
AB 2
ZZ 2
BC 1
CC 1
```

Thank you

Comment: table(df1[[1]])`

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

## Using the table() function

```
data <- c("AB","ZZ","BC","AB","ZZ","CC")
table(data)
```

## Output

`data AB BC CC ZZ  2  1  1  2`

Comment: Can i do list = [colnames(data)] ?

Comment: Yes, you can do list = [colnames(data)] to get the names of the columns in the data. To get the number of times a string is repeated, you can use the count() function in Python. For example:

Comment: why write python code when the question tags R?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't catch that, I switched up my response,You can take a look now.